# Change SASS variable on breakpoint

Tags: css, sass, less

Is it possible to change SASS variable on breakpoint?
The code below is just for example what I want to achieve

```
$flex-direction: row;

@include breakpoint(768){
  $flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this and in your example it wouldn't make sense either. Just write the code this way:

```
.your-classname {

    flex-direction: row;

    @include breakpoint(768) {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

There is no need to use scss variables for values/properties that never change. The value/keyword `column` is not going to change as long as the CSS specs are not rewritten completely. If you use colors or size-values like `px` etc it can make sense to use scss variables.

Maybe you want to use custom properties - see more about here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties